# JavaScript null is not an object and center rectangle with variable height vertical

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a Line in the middle of the Screen. Centered on this line there should be a rectangle which I can change the position and size at some event (like clicking on it). After changing the X Position of the recangle it always needs do be fully on the screen and I needs to change at least more then 30px.

Here is my current code:

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>B1</title>
  <style type="text/css">

     .line {
        position:absolute;
        top:50%;
        width:100%;
        height:1px;
        background:black;
    }   

     .rectangle {
         position:absolute;
         top: 50%;
         left: 80%;
        width: 200px;
        height: 100px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        background: red;
    }

    </style>
   </head>
  <body>
  <script type="text/javascript">

    function changeRec() {
        var elementStyle = document.getElementById("rectangle").style;
        var newX = (Math.random() * window.screen.availWidth - 30) + 30;
        if (newX > window.screen.availWidth - document.getElementById("rectangle").clientWidth) {
            newX = window.screen.availWidth - document.getElementById("rectangle").clientWidth;
            newX;
        }
        elementStyle.position = "relative";
    }

     document.onkeydown = onKey;
     function onKey(e) { if (e == null) {
             e = window.event;
         }
        switch (e.which || e.charCode || e.keyCode) { 
            case 32:
            // space
                changeRec();
            break;
            case 65: // a
            break;
            case 66:
            // b
        } 
     }

  </script>

    <hr class="line">
    <div class="rectangle" id="rectangle" ></div>
```

I have two problems:

1. The rectangle is not centered on the line on the Y-Axis.Because the height should be variable, I can't just set a fixed margin.
2. My changeRec() method does not work properly. Sometimes it sets the X Position to a value outside of the Screen.

Im still very new to JS, CSS and HTML so any help is appreciated,

Comment: java != javascript

Comment: Where’s the element with the ID `rectangle`?

Comment: The first error you can fix by using document.getElementsByClassName("rectangle")[0]

Comment: @Xufox you are right, I misread the snippet. Removing my comment.

Comment: Sorry guys, I forgot to give the rectangle an ID. I changed this and noticed the changeRec() method does not work properly. I updated the Code and the 2nd Problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I fiddled with your code and appear to have it working. Here are the issues you seemed to have:

**Vertical alignment of rectangle**

One solution to achieving vertical alignment like this is to use transform:translateY, like this:

```
top:50%;
transform:translateY(-50%);
```

For some reason however, and I hope someone cleverer than me can explain, to have the rectangle appear properly centred I used translateY(-43%). Maybe something weird about hRules...

EDIT: It's indeed because hr and its margins. I set its margins to 0 and translateY(-50%) works as intended.

As for the move Rect problem, several issues:

For selecting the rectangle, as people has said in the comments, you need to use:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("rectangle")[0]
```

Though with your edit that's no longer necessary, I suppose.

in your code, this line:

```
var newX = (Math.random() * window.screen.availWidth - 30) + 30;
```

Why -30? The rectangle is 200px wide. Also, the -30 should be in parentheses along with the availWidth. For the sake of the snippet below I changed availWidth to document.body.clientWidth to account for the iFrame. So we have:

```
var newX = (Math.random() * (document.body.clientWidth -200));
```

Also, you change the rectangle's position to relative for no clear reason. I just removed that.

Finally, when giving the rectangle a new left value for its style, don't forget to add "px".

Anyway, here's a working snippet:

```js
function changeRec() {
        var elementStyle = document.getElementsByClassName("rectangle")[0].style;
        var newX = (Math.random() * (document.body.clientWidth -200));
        elementStyle.left = newX+"px";
    }

     document.onkeydown = onKey;
     function onKey(e) { if (e == null) {
             e = window.event;
         }
        switch (e.which || e.charCode || e.keyCode) { 
            case 32:
            // space
                changeRec();
            break;
            case 65: // a
            break;
            case 66:
            // b
        } 
     }
```

```css
.line {
        position:absolute;
        top:50%;
        width:100%;
        height:1px;
        margin:0px;
        background:black;
    }   

     .rectangle {
        position:absolute;
        top: 50%;
        transform: translateY(-50%);
        left: 50%;
        width: 200px;
        height: 100px;
        background: red;
    }
```

```html
<hr class="line">
<div class="rectangle"></div>
```

Comment: thanks a lot for the code! Works great! With the line `var newX = (Math.random() * window.screen.availWidth - 30) + 30;`I wanted to make sure, that the rectangle moves for at least 30px, it has nothing todo with the rectangle size. Now I see that it won't work this way because Im not changing the position relative to the rectangle but relative to the screen.

Comment: I just noticed that `transform: translateY(-50%);` doesn't seem to be the answer to the center problem. When changing the height of the element it is not properly centered.

Comment: Heya! I tried changing the height on the snippet in my answer, and it's still centred. What behaviour are you seeing?